# Behavior of wrapping text inside Firefox's textareas

Tags: html, css, firefox

TL;DR :

How can I make the two lines line up in the textarea in this HTML exemple?

`<textarea style="width: 200px; font-size:12px; text-align: right;">Pellentesque vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo</textarea>`

---

Longer version :

Is there a way to remove the spaces Firefox leaves at the end of a lines inside a  when the browser decides to wrap the text to the next line?

When you perform a line break manually (pressing enter while typing in the textarea) or when you reach the end, this spacing will not be present and therefore the alignment is off between the first few lines and the last line of the paragraphs in the textarea.

All of this is more obvious when you text-align:right the textarea.

Webkit doesn't behave like this as it seems to ignore the space character that allows the line wrap, keeping everything aligned. Since someone does it differently, I'm hoping a -moz-whatever could help me.

Any help or ideas will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/linmic/Qah5b/) for you, hope that helps. Cheers.